# How to see HTML rendered response of AJAX request in Network tab in Safari browser?

Tags: safari, safari-web-inspector

**I see raw HTML code instead of rendered response as we can see in Chrome and other browsers**

*Here is screenshot of what I see*
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNfgd.png)

I want to see this response rendered as HTML